# HP ProLiant DL380 G6 with 2 x Intel x5650 CPUs

Tags: hardware, hp, hp-proliant

I have an old HP DL380 G6 server, I am trying to upgrade the processor. I added 2x X5650. but each time I powered the server on, the fans stat working loudly and keep like that. the server never never booted up.
any suggestion?

Comment: Did you ensure the server was up to the latest version of all the various drivers/bios's via the SPP before adding the new processors?

Comment: @Chopper3 Sounds like the server freezes before any drives are loaded, so I don't think it could be a driver problem. More likely the new CPU is incompatible with either the MB or the BIOS. If it is an incompatibility with the BIOS, then a BIOS update might fix it. Obviously the old CPU would have to be installed again to perform the BIOS update.

Comment: @kasperd - that CPU model is compatible but probably does need a BIOS update, they also need the extra fan/s for the second processor too.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to run BIOS upgrades before attempting this transition.

- Were you upgrading from an Intel 5500-series CPU?
- Did you previously have two CPUs?
- When the fan are running loudly, are there any messages on the screen?
- What do the server's health LEDs display on the front panel?
- Intel 5600-series CPUs are compatible with this platform with several edge-case exceptions.
- Do you recall the version of the BIOS on the machine right now?

This is basic hardware troubleshooting. Break the machine down to its bare configuration (*of course, AFTER you upgrade firmware using the [HP Service Pack for ProLiant DVD](http://h17007.www1.hp.com/us/en/enterprise/servers/products/service_pack/spp/index.aspx)*).

- Try with *one* CPU and one DIMM.
- If that works, try with *two* CPUs and one DIMM in each CPU memory bank.
- If that works, populate the RAM fully and boot.
- Watch POST messages closely and use them to guide you.

There's not much else to it.

Comment: I checked everything I can. The Bios is  P62 07/02/2013. All status LED are normal. The two CPUs of X5650 were implemented on another G7 server and they were functioning well.
I updated the power controller, then the Fans returned to normal operation. but still the server not booting up. HPsum says every thing is uptodate.
nothing appears on the screen (idle). its only working when I use single CPU.

Comment: The ILO shows the following information when two CPUs implemented:
Proc 1: 2667 MHz 
Execution technology: 6/6 cores; 12 maximum threads 
Memory technology: 64-bit capable 
Processor 1 Internal L1 Cache: 192 KB 
Processor 1 Internal L2 Cache: 1536 KB 
Processor 1 Internal L3 Cache: 12288 KB 
Proc 2: unavailable

Comment: @Ahamd Please inspect the LGA motherboard socket for the second CPU. Look closely an see if you can detect any bent or missing pins. That's probably the issue here.

Comment: Solved

I know everybody will laugh. The solution is just [Clear Bios] :D

Thanks for all.

Comment: Do note that HP now only provide firmware and bios updates to users with valid warranties.

Comment: They offer critical updates for everybody and recommended updates for customers.